# Built in terminal extensions showing different files than default bash terminal

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I'm attempting to use a Sublime Text 3 extension *Terminus*, on Clear Linux, but am having a strange issue I did not run into on Ubuntu 20 - the same issue applied to the other similarly functioning extension *Terminal View*:

Most commands, including `sudo`, `python`, `node` etc. that work normally on the default system terminal (Bash) will return `command not found` in the extension terminals. This seems clearly like an issue with `$PATH`, so I found the path variable in the default terminal, and placed it in `~/.bashrc` and  `~/.profile` along with echo commands to make sure they run - sure enough they do run in the extension terminal and they do affect its path variable, but it does not solve the issue. Here are some logs.

```bsh
~/.bashrc executed
~/.profile executed
Matt@jdrive:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin/haswell:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/3rd-party/bin
Matt@jdrive:~$ sudo
sh: sudo: command not found
Matt@jdrive:~$ bash
~/.bashrc executed
Matt@jdrive:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin/haswell:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/3rd-party/bin
Matt@jdrive:~$ sudo
bash: sudo: command not found
```

Which also confirm that the issue is present whether `sh` or `bash` is running. I have confirmed the `$PATH` in default terminal (bash) is identical, and the expected commands are found. Finally, I decide to simply see what the path variable in the default and built in terminal lead to.

TLDR:

To my surprise, listing the files in `/usr/bin/` will lead to different results depending on the terminal (default system terminal or built in Sublime extension), which directly correlates to which commands that terminal is able to find. Even stranger is that the built in terminal is not a strict subset, there are some files in its `/usr/bin` that are not in the default terminal's listing, though most files are missing from the built in.

Further more creating a file in one terminal's root will not actually show up in the other. I checked the downloads folder and they are consistent - possible ruling out some strange cross drive action.

Really this has me at a complete loss, as I have no idea how navigating to the same directories is producing different results in this case - its like one terminal is in an alternate dimension. Hopefully I'm about to learn something fundamental about how terminal's are ran that explains this issue.

There are initial commands to open the built in shells with defaults `-i` and `-l`  - interactive' and 'login' respectively - while that is an avenue for fiddling I'm not sure what exactly to try there.

Comment: How have you installed Sublime Text? Are you using Snap or other sandbox-like environment?

Comment: @gronostaj I've used Clear Linux's software center.